# Cannot create property 'validator' on string

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-forms

I am trying to create an Angular 5 nested reactive form.

I started by creating a flat form, which worked as expected, but as soon as I extract part of my form and place it in as a child component I get an error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'addressFormGroup'

If I just start typing another error is then displayed in the console

> ERROR TypeError: this.form.get is not a function

What am I doing wrong? I've read several threads and tutorials to try and solve this, but I think i'm missing something obvious.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Address } from '../Property';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'app-property-form',
templateUrl: './property-form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./property-form.component.css']
})
export class PropertyFormComponent implements OnInit {

propertyForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
}

createForm() {
    this.propertyForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        saleOrLet: ['Sales', Validators.required],
        addressFormGroup: this.initAddress()
    })
}

initAddress() {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
        houseNameNumber: '',
        address2: '',
        postCode1: '',
        postCode2: ''
    })
}
}
```

Working form

```
<form [formGroup]="propertyForm" novalidate>
<fieldset>
<legend>Address</legend>
<div formGroupName="addressFormGroup">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      House Name Or Number:
      <input placeholder="15 Nursery ave" formControlName="houseNameNumber">
    </label>
  </div>
  ...other inputs follow the same pattern...
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Broken form (when split in to parent child format)

*Parent*

```
<form [formGroup]="propertyForm" novalidate>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Address 2</legend>
    <app-property-form-address group="addressFormGroup"></app-property-form-address>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

*Child*

```
<div [formGroup]="group">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label>
      House Name Or Number:
      <input placeholder="15 Nursery ave" formControlName="houseNameNumber">
    </label>
  </div>
  ...other inputs follow the same pattern...
</div>
```

*Child component*

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-property-form-address',
   templateUrl: './property-form-address.component.html',
})
export class PropertyFormAddressComponent {
    @Input() group: FormGroup;
}
```

Comment: Inside initAddress use array. Something like address2:[‘’]

Comment: Your @grup is a string, not a FormControl or FormGroup. Try <pp-property-form-address group="propertyForm.get('addressFormGroup')"..>. Anyway, you can try make a "custom Form Control", not, simple component

Comment: @tony09uk i have same issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're passing the form group name as a string rather than a reference to the formGroup and trying to typecast it as a FormGroup (`group="addressFormGroup"`). `group="addressFormGroup"` doesn't pass the formGroup object, it passes a string with the value of `addressFormGroup`.

Comment: What was the solution? Typecasting to FormGroup like this didn't  work for me: `<app-property-form-address group="<FormGroup>propertyForm.get('addressFormGroup')"></app-property-form-address>`

Comment: @annepic try [group]="addressFormGroup" - by calling group="" you're still passing a string. You need to use property binding with angular, I suggest you read up on template syntax and binding in general (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

Answer (score 8):

You can get a similar error message if you have:

```
<input formControl="startDate">
```

From the docs it should be:

```
<input formControlName="startDate">
```

And everything should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

I had a same issue and I was passing `form` object as a value like `formGroup="form"` but you need to bind the `form` object using `[]` aroung as `[formGroup]="form"`.

See the example below:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    // form-controls
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem occured because of the wrong implementation of formgroup and formControl. Fixed this by the following implementation.

`formGroup=''` renamed to `formGroupName=''`.

`formControl=''` renamed to `formControlName=''`.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was on the control side, I had to change from

```
<input formControl="startDate">
```

to this

```
<input [formControl]="startDate">
```

So this structure should work

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    // form-controls
    <input [formControl]="startDate">
</form>
```